# node_modules scripts do not access the root global variables of the installation

Tags: node.js

Node.js / node_modules.
Question: How can I make a script in node_modules / ws / lib /, have access to the global variables declared in the spapp myapp.js located at the root of the node.js installation?
Many thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Doesn't `global.myvar` work? I'm not sure, because I don't do global variables.